# Get number of posts in each category since last visit

Tags: get-posts

I can think of a number of ways to go about doing this. I'm looking for the most efficient way. Menu looks like this:

catArchive1 [num_new_posts]  catArchive2 [num_new_posts] catArchive3 [num_new_posts]

^^[num_new_posts] being the number of new posts

Assuming we have a cookie value set for the users last visit `$_COOKIE['lastvisit']`.

I could do something like the follow for EACH menu/category

```
$args = array(
 'category' => $cat_id,
 'posts_per_page' => -1,
 'date_query'     => array( 'after' => $_COOKIE['lastvisit'] ),
 );

$new_posts = get_posts($args);
$num_posts = count($num_posts); // Number of new posts
```

Of course, this is another query for each menu item. Any ideas how to combine this into one and still know how many new posts in each category?

Comment: A single query for all categories, since `lastvisit`?  Would require more code to iterate through the result manually but save on the expensive multi-query approach.

Answer (score 0):

use wpdb query instead:
"SELECT DISTINCT wposts.* 
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta ON wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON (wposts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
    LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE post_date >= {$lastvisit}
    AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
";

I did not test this but should work. I also suggest you to use prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing one query and looping results and organizing.

```
/**
* Calculates number of posts since a users last visit.
* @return array Organized by category and total.
*/
function denverite_posts_by_cat_since_last_visit(){
session_start();
$post_counts = array();

// Set session value as the time stamp of the users last visit if not yest set.
// use this value to get "new posts" during users sessions. 
if(!isset($_SESSION['denveritelastvisit'])){
    $_SESSION['denveritelastvisit'] = $_COOKIE['denveritelastvisit'];
}

if ($_SESSION['denveritelastvisit']) {

    $lastvisit = date('Y-m-d G:i:s', $_SESSION['denveritelastvisit']);
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'date_query' => array(
            'after' => $lastvisit 
        )
    ); 
    $new_posts = get_posts( $args );

    // all posts since visitors last visit. 
    $post_counts['total_posts'] = count( $new_posts );

    // Loop all posts and count posts for each category.
    foreach ( $new_posts as $new_p ) {
        $cats = get_the_category( $new_p->ID );

        if (is_array( $cats )) {

            foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {

                if ( in_array($post_counts[$cat->slug], $post_counts) ) {
                    $post_counts[$cat->slug] = $post_counts[$cat->slug] + 1;
                } else {
                    $post_counts[$cat->slug] = 1;
                }

            }

        }

    }
 }
 // Overwrites last visit cookie 
 denverite_lastvisit_set_cookie();
 return $post_counts;
}
```